# Virtual Directory pointing to another server

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, virtual-directory

I have 2 web servers hosted in Azure (Website - Windows - IIS):

- example.com - running custom made ASP.NET website.
- blog.example.com - Running WordPress.

I want to marge those two website into "example.com". When the user will enter the blog, the URL will be http://example.com/blog/... (instead of blog.copyleaks.com)

So, as I see it, I have two options:

1. Create a new virtual directory in example.com: "/blog/" and move all the files from blog.example.com into it. Now, blog.example.com is no longer in use.
2. Create a new virtual directory in example.com: "/blog/" but instead moving the files into the new virtual directory, the server will execute quite redirect. The url will not changed but the pages will served from another server. Is this possible?

The first option (number 1) is bad option for me because of security. WordPress is wellkown because of it security issues...

I want to implement the second (2) options. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

Take A look at Application Request Routing (ARR) which can act as a reverse proxy: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing